# How to get Parent Table "Record Id" (Auto generated id) of SalesForce in MuleSoft

Tags: mulesoft

I am trying to access parent "Record ID" (Auto generated ID) in a MULESOFT Flow and store it into child table of SalesForce and store that record id in one variable and pass it to child table through DataWeave Transformation. I am using one flow for this task. Can anyone please tell me how can i get parent table Record ID? Thanks.

Here is my flow Confi. XML file

```
<flow name="shoppingcartpocmcpostsfuserFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/customeruser" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="4851f81e-2a1b-4e5e-a34f-cc328e6dd23d">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[{
    Name: payload.ShoppingCartUser.ShoppingCartUserName,
    FirstName__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.FirstName,
    LastName__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.LastName,
    EmailID__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.EmailID,
    PhoneNumber__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.PhoneNumber,
    CompanyName__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.Company,
    CustomerType__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.Customer_Type
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" type="MS_ShoppingCartUser__c" doc:name="Salesforce Connector for User Details">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:create>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[flowVars.id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message for User Address" metadata:id="4851f81e-2a1b-4e5e-a34f-cc328e6dd23d">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[{
    AddressLine1__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.AddressLine_1,
    AddressLine2__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.AddressLine_2,
    CountyName__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.County,
    City__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.City,
    Country__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.Country,
    State__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.State,
    ZipCode__c: payload.ShoppingCartUser.Zipcode,
    EmailID__c: id
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" type="MS_ShoppingCart__c" doc:name="Salesforce Connector for User Address">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:create>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Note that MuleSoft is a company name. You are referring to the product called Mule Runtime 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The `sfdc:create` operation will return a 'Result' https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/salesforce/salesforce-connector-reference-96#Result

It has an 'Id' field. You can access the id using 'payload.Id'

Note in your example you will need to remove the object-to-string to access it. It will also overwrite your payload. So you need to use an enricher if you need the same payload values in your second transform.